# jquery adding hover to animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a div that animates in and out on a continuous loop with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
setInterval(function () {
    $("#possum-animate").animate({
    bottom:"32"
    }, 3000 ).delay(10000).animate({
    bottom:"-70"
    }, 3000).delay(10000);
}, 10000);  
});
```

How can I add in a hover function so that if you hover the div it completes the animation to show, and then when you hover out it hides the div and starts the continuous loop again.

Comment: did you check this link out? http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    function timeFunction(){

        var timeInterval = setInterval(function () {        

        $("#possum-animate").animate({

         bottom:"32"

    }, 3000 ).delay(10000).animate({

        bottom:"-70"

    }, 3000).delay(10000);

  }, 10000);     

return timeInterval;

}

// Start animating on page load

var timeInterval = timeFunction();

$("#possum-animate").bind({

    mouseenter: function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        clearTimeout(timeInterval);
        $("#possum-animate").clearQueue(); 
        $("#possum-animate").stop();

    },

    mouseleave: function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        timeInterval = timeFunction();

    } 

});

});
```

Comment: thankyou Sajjad. This acts in the same way as my original code, what is it supposed to do on hover?

Comment: well it stops the continuous loop when you hover over and restarts it when mouse leaves the div. Now you do whatever you want in the mouseenter function.

Comment: And if you want to stop the animation on hover then use this 
$("#possum-animate").clearQueue(); $("#possum-animate").stop();

Comment: the above code does nothing on hover, the loop still functions with or without hover

Comment: Hi sajjad, this is very close, it's getting better. When I hover it stops the animation in its tracks, is there a way to make it finish the current animation (the first movement up) before it stops?

Comment: Thanks sajjid for your very clear help. I added in the .animate lines in the bind event to get it to where I needed it. It now cycles every 10 seconds, unless you hover, and when you hover out, it starts the cycle again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flag = true;
    setInterval(function() {
                if (flag) {
                    $("#possum-animate").animate({
                                bottom : "32"
                            }, 3000).delay(10000).queue(function() {
                                $("#possum-animate").animate({
                                            bottom : "-70"
                                        }, 3000)
                            });
                }
            }, 10000);

    $("#possum-animate").hover(function() {
                flag = false;
                $(this).stop().animate({
                            bottom : "32"
                        }, 3000);
            }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                            bottom : "-70"
                        }, 3000);
                flag = true;
            });
});
```

Comment: Very close, it starts the animation on hover and stops if you hover out, however once you hover out, the div animates to its shown state and stays there.

Comment: Yeh same behaviour, it seems to run the animation again when you hover out. Thanks for your help